# How do I remove https from wp_list_pages()

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to remove the https:// and replace it with a non secure link for my wordpress navigation. This only happens when I view a secure page the wp_list_pages adds https:// Ive tried this

```
$sslnav = wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&exclude=');
$sslnav = str_replace("https", "http", $sslnav);
echo $sslnav;
```

but the nav links remain the same with https in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the echo query var in the arguments.  This will stop WordPress from showing the list of pages and return the result in your variable.

```
$sslnav = wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&exclude=&echo=0');
$sslnav = str_replace("https", "http", $sslnav);
echo $sslnav;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this function in your theme's **functions.php** file:

```
function wp_list_pages_custom() {
  $array = array();
  $pages = wp_list_pages('echo=0&amp;title_li=');

  foreach($pages as $key => $page)
  {
    $array[$key] = str_replace('https', 'http', $page);
  }

  return $array;
}
```

Now instead of using `wp_list_pages`, use `wp_list_pages_custom`.